# How to extend the maximum number of SQL variables supported by sqllite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite, laravel-5.4

I'm working with  Laravel 5.4 configured with **sqlite** database.

I have some tables, including an 'appointments' table that has **rows** about **2000+**.

Whenever I tried to load this table there occurs a `Query Exception` that says:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 too many SQL variables
```

How to overcome [image: this scenario] ?

---

There seems no problem with other tables inside the same database.I googled and found out(maybe) it's something related to the limit of SQL variables supported by sqlite3. Any idea?

**UPDATE:** I had deleted the whole records inside the table and now it's fine!

Comment: Where do these 2000 variables come from?

Comment: I have an admin panel(Laravel Back pack)  where I could add appointments to the table. These 2000+ rows are added manually in the course of testing the project!

Comment: The max number of bind variables is a compile time option of SQLite (default is 999 - https://sqlite.org/limits.html#max_variable_number). If you want more, you have to recompile sqlite (which is quite easy - https://sqlite.org/howtocompile.html). However, maybe you can can change the number of customers fetched in one bulk?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can scale your solution to a virtually unlimited number of values by inserting your list of 2000+ values into a table (either temp table or a permanent one) that you then reference in your sql via `where id in (select id from my_table)` or using `inner join` or `exists()`. Using an inner join and a permanent table, you can set explicit indexes which might be more useful than relying on the query optimizer to optimize `in()` or `exists()`:

```
select customers.* from customers inner join my_table on customers.id = my_table.list_element_id
```

If your list of 2000+ variables will change every time, you can insert them during the transaction and delete them afterwards. You just have to make sure you insulate your table values from bleeding into other concurrent processes (e.g. have another key in the table for thread_id or similar identifier unique to the calling transaction).